# How to increase a integer every second

Tags: python, time

I'm making a dodging game in Python where I want the score to increase by 1 every second, but the problem is that I don't know how. It would be nice to find a solution where I don't have to change too much of my code.

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you iterate through the game loop, you can check the current time with the time library. You can then check if it has been a second since the last time you awarded a point.
It might look something like this:

```
import time
points = 0
currentTime = time.time()
previousPointAwardedTime = currentTime

while gameRunning == True:
    ...
    currentTime = time.time()
    if (currentTime - previousPointAwardedTime) >= 1:
        points += 1
        previousPointAwardedTime = currentTime
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, but I also want to ask a question, why do you have to use it in an if statement?

Comment: This if statement will determine if a full second has passed. If your game loops in 0.001 seconds, the if statement will prevent a point from being added until 1000 iterations of the while loop have occurred.

Comment: oh, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

you can try using [asyncio](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

```
import asyncio

score = 0  # starting game with a score of zero


async def s():
    global score
    score += 1 #increasing score by 1
    await asyncio.sleep(1)  #waiting for 1 second

while True:  #while game is running
    asyncio.run(s()) #calling function
    print(score)  #printing score
```